# Losing Focus issue visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, lost-focus

I have a serious problem with my visual studio 2013 
suddenly yesterday it began a "Losing Focus" Problem

I mean when I open visual studio it starts to lose focus every few seconds which is really annoying especially while writing code

and not just visual studio, but all other applications they start a loop of losing focus every few seconds but, once I close VS 2013, everything goes back to normal again 
kindly help me with this issue as it's driving me crazy

Comment: Can you explain what "loosing focus" means in more technical terms?

Comment: you are typing in VS and it losses focus and you are typing somewhere else?

Comment: Try rebooting the computer, because the problem sounds like it is system wide. @Fadi

Comment: @ the Monster What I meant that after few seconds from typing in the IDE  , the letters are not shown which forced me every time to click in the field to get the focus and complete typing

Comment: @ Valamas this issue happens not only in the VS , but also if the VS is opened and and i switch for example to view a webpade or facebook it requires every few seconds to click ot get the focus back and continue browsing or typing

Comment: @Work Smarter i did 10s of times rebooting and i acquired all the updates , also i'm having kaspersky internet security

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because there is **some "background working" application** that causes this. Visual studio has nothing wrong with your problem.

e.g. showing a window (then losing focus) then hiding it immediately, so one cannot observe it.

Try using Task Manager to find out. Also, you can check start-up apps (with `msconfig` tool)